# PhpStorm theme installation

Tags: 12.04, php

I want to install PhpStorm color scheme from XML.
Official PhpStorm's IDE website says

> *To install a theme, download the corresponging xml file,  copy to ~/Library/Preferences/RubyMine10/colors/ (Mac OS X) or
>   C:\Users\%username%.RubyMine10\config\colors\ (Windows) and restart
>   RubyMine. Then go to IDE Settings | Editor | Colors and select your
>   theme.*

However, nothing is said about Ubuntu. I tried to find anything similar to "Library" folder inside of PhpStorm folder but failed. How can I install the theme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Ubuntu you need to download the theme XML file and copy it to folder

```
~/.WebIdeXX/config/colors
```

In my case it is ~/.WebIde50/config/colors

- Restart phpstorm
- Select the new theme by navigating to

  **Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts**

Hope this helps

Comment: that folder does not exist in my case

Comment: simply create one if you have windows copy the settings and import in the ubuntu does solve my problem doing that

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on PHPStorm10 on MacOS

Answer (score 1):

For PhpStorm2016.1 and .2, the location now is:

`~/.PhpStorm2016.2/config/colors`

I was looking for this for long time and I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For **versions 2020 and younger**, the location is now:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
```

i.e.
`~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2022.1`
or
`~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1`

After that the principle stays the same:

- Create folder `colors`
- Copy XML files here
- **Restart** PhpStorm (or any other IDE)