# PhpStorm theme installation folder not found

Tags: 14.04, php

I am new to ubuntu and I am trying to install theme for PhpStorm. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228465/phpstorm-theme-installation)  point out the folder `~/.WebIde50/config/colors` but I am unable to find `~/.Webide50` folder.

Comment: Can you be more precise and tell us what you did until know to search for this folder ? (Commands at console, Actions in GUI, ...)

Comment: What commands did you use ? A simple `ls` or trying to access it with nautilus won't show anything as files which names are preceeded by a `.` are hidden in Unix. Try `ls -a ~` instead, or try directly `cd ~/.Webide50`.

Comment: In my system it is `~/.WebIde60` folder. Check whether that folder exists.

Comment: I have tried `cd ~/.Webide50` and it didn't work. I also tried `ls -a ~` in home dir but no folder with this worked. I have searched in ubuntu 14.04 my computer but it seems nothing is working. How can I change theme then?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -a ~
```

There should be ".WebIde70" directory in there. You should next download some-theme.xml from http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/ to your Downloads folder.

```
cp ~/Downloads/some-theme.xml ~/.WebIde70/config/colors
```

When you open PhpStorm next time you should go to **File->Settings->IDE Settings-> Editor->Colors & Fonts** and change the theme from the drop down menu.

If you have PhpStorm8:

```
cp ~/Downloads/some-theme.xml ~/.WebIde80/config/colors
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `locate` command?

```
locate <foldername>
```